# Why would my app code show "Could not find a declaration file for module ... " when the library has an index.d.ts file?

Tags: node.js, typescript, typescript-typings

This is the library that's causing the problem: [simple-social-signin](https://github.com/omarryhan/simple-social-signin).

To my understanding, the library doesn't need to have a `declare module` statement. What might be wrong?

To reproduce the bug:

1. Install the library
2. Import:

```js
import { getGoogleUserInfo, getFacebookUserInfo } from 'simple-social-signin';
```

---

Also, not sure if that would help, but when I was publishing this package I got this weird error, even though the package was still published and I got the "successfully published" email

```
npm ERR! code E403
npm ERR! 403 403 Forbidden - PUT https://registry.npmjs.org/simple-social-signin - You cannot publish over the previously published versions: 1.0.9.
npm ERR! 403 In most cases, you or one of your dependencies are requesting
npm ERR! 403 a package version that is forbidden by your security policy.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/omar/.npm/_logs/2020-05-18T20_47_59_780Z-debug.log
```

I checked the logs and they don't have anything meaningful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to restart VScode for that error to disappear. Closing the tab didn't fix it. Weird...